# How can I port audio of specific applications audio on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, audio-streaming, asio, ableton-live, reaper

I'm trying to grab the audio from a couple applications and port them to my DAW program (ableton live or reaper) then to my streaming program (obs-studio). I've been attempting this with ASIO4ALL, Jack, and VB-CABLE  (Virtual cable for non asio applications).

I am used to using sound flower on mac n looking for advice other apps or configurations to get this software working. Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use a combo of Virtual Audio Cable and Ableton Live 9 to capture audio from all kinds of things that play through my speakers. I will gladly explain how I do it. (I am using Windows 7.)

**Here's how:**

- Create one cable in Virtual Audio Cable
- The only "CONNECTED SOURCE" box in VAC checked is "LINE".
- Then LINE 1 can be routed to the playback channel in the Recording
  tab of the Windows Audio Control Panel by checking the "Listen" box and applying the changes.
- You are then able to change the input device in the Preferences of Ableton to Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable).
- After that create a single audio channel and make sure it is routed to EXT In. with Stereo channels 1/2 enabled. ("Monitor" on this channel set to OFF)

I then saved this as a template for quick and easy Ableton audio capture of all incoming audio called "High Quality Ripper"

You will have to mess with some of the input latency settings in Abelton in order to stop glitchy or choppy recording.

Hope this helps you or someone asking this similar question.